# show if checkbox is checked PHP in edit page

Tags: php, database, checkbox

how to show multiple checkboxes checked in Core PHP Edit Page:

ps: array data

[DB img][1]
[enter image description here][2]

```
<?php
$tenses = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from tenses");
if(sizeof($tenses) > 0)
{
foreach($tenses as $tens)
{
?>
<div class="span3" style="margin-left:30px;">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="tenses[]" value="<?php echo $tens['pktenseid']; ?>"> <?php echo $tens['tense_name']; ?></label></div>
<?php
}
}
?>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xCZT.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARzp.png
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to do and how you tried to accomplish this in detail. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: what values are typically held within the `pktenseid` column in the db? It looks like it is an `ID` -  rather than either a 1 or 0 which would be easier

Comment: @RamRaider yes its pktenseid table ID of tenses , tenses[] is the multiple checkboxes i want to show checked values in Edit page...

Comment: usually I'd suggest that to show a checkbox as checked you would compare a known value in the database ( ie: a `status` column or similar ) with a known value ( say 1 or 0 ) ~ if it is `1` then it is checked etc. With an `ID` the number is always increasing so how do you determine if it is checked or not? There is no way to do that

Comment: what is the purpose of the checkboxes? Are they to indicate that the record passes some criteria or that the record is marked for deletion,update etc?

Comment: @RamRaider Checkboxes are the multiple selection of the tenses inserted in to the category table in array form like (1,2,3) but now i want to edit tenses page and want to show already checked boxes ? Can you please change on this code ?

Comment: you should add the necessary table schemas and sample data because without knowing how the data relates or what it is this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @RamRaider here the structure of my DB ? pktenseid ID inserted into other table

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="tenses[]" value="<?php echo $tens['pktenseid']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($tens['tense_name'],$tensesarr)) { echo "checked"; } ?> > <?php echo $tens['tense_name']; ?>